# spring-boot: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 17

Tags: spring-boot

Just going through [spring-boot tutorial](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started.first-application.run) and getting stuck on step 4.4.4 executing `$ mvn spring-boot:run`

Here's the error:

```
$ mvn spring-boot:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------< com.example:myproject >------------------------
[INFO] Building myproject 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ myproject >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/dnatochy/development/springboot/testapp1/src/main/resources
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/dnatochy/development/springboot/testapp1/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ myproject ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/dnatochy/development/springboot/testapp1/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.078 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-07-26T21:27:48-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project myproject: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 17 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Everything I can find on Google similar to this error points to the mismatch of java version used by maven, but this is not the case

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_333"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_333-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.333-b02, mixed mode)

$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_333

$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.8.6 (84538c9988a25aec085021c365c560670ad80f63)
Maven home: /Users/myuser/tools/apache-maven-3.8.6
Java version: 1.8.0_333, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_333.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "12.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_333.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: _"error points to the mismatch of java version used by maven, but this is not the case"_ - but it is. You are using java 8, and trying to compile java 17 application.

Comment: Thank you @1615903! After installing java 17 and adding import statement the issues was resolved.

Answer (score 38):

You should check which Java version is configured in the JAVA_HOME.
Use: `mvn -version`
You should see something like this from `mvn` output

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.8.5 (3599d3414f046de2324203b78ddcf9b5e4388aa0)
Maven home: path\apache-maven-3.8.5
Java version: 17.0.3.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: path\Java\jdk-17.0.3.1
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

You can also follow this post for more solutions.
https://mkyong.com/maven/maven-error-invalid-target-release-17/

Comment: Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Java\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 17.0.5, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.5
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 11", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Everything seems in order here: error still persists :/

Answer (score 13):

make sure Maven is using a JAVA version that is same or newer than your target.

- update your JAVA_HOME to the newer java you installed.
- close any old terminal (even if using VSCode)
- and open & run the `mvn -version` command. make sure the
  "runtime:" is pointing to your new JAVA path

Answer (score 7):

Go back to your pom.xml change the java version to what you find in your : `mvn -v`.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, this issue was due to the lower Java version which was present in my machine. I was on Java 17 and update to Java 18 and setting the same in the worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

As @1615903 pointed out I needed java 17. After installing it, I started getting compilation errors

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/myuser/development/springboot/testapp1/src/main/java/MyApplication.java:[1,2] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class RestController
[ERROR] /Users/myuser/development/springboot/testapp1/src/main/java/MyApplication.java:[2,2] cannot find symbol
  symbol: class EnableAutoConfiguration
[ERROR] /Users/myuser/development/springboot/testapp1/src/main/java/MyApplication.java:[5,10] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RequestMapping
  location: class MyApplication
[ERROR] /Users/myuser/development/springboot/testapp1/src/main/java/MyApplication.java:[11,17] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable SpringApplication
```

After adding import statements to MyApplication.java, the app compiled and ran

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
```

Answer (score 1):

u can either set 17 in < target> and < source> in < configuration> of maven-compiler-plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>17</source>
        <target>17</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

OR

set 17 in maven-compiler-source (and target) in < properties>

```
<maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
```

then u need to set jdk 17 in JAVA_HOME ( u can check it with mvn -v command )

note that: with ( for example ) jdk-11 u can compile projects with lower java version but in order to compile projects with java 11 u have to set jdk-11 or above.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when I used 'Spring Boot Extension Pack' version 0.2.1 from Visual Studio Code. So, I used an older version 0.2.0 of it and this fixed my issue.
If any of those following solutions not working, you can try this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse, check this run configurations to confirm jre version set at runtime for maven
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

1. Found my java 17 home with command:`/usr/libexec/java_home`

result:

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-17.jdk/Contents/Home

2. Checked mvn file:`vi ~/.mavenrc` 
   and replace JAVA_HOME with 17 above

Answer (score 0):

**Note** : this coz while project creation , most of we create project by default without checking our maven version and java version.

Step 1: Check java version running in your system
cmd -> java --version

Step 2: Change java version in POX.xml file accordingly for my case it was java 8

```
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change your project *pom.xml* java version to 17.

```xml
<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
```

And then change the `JAVA_HOME` variable to JDK 17 HOME.

If you don't want change your `JAVA_HOME` for all projects, just specify Java 17 home path for this command only. Try this:

```bash
JAVA_HOME=~/path/to/your/jdk17/home mvn spring-boot:run
```

For my Mac OSX environment, my jdk 17 home path is `~/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-17.0.8.1/Contents/Home/`